# Cannot query a second result set without looping through the first result set

Tags: zend-framework2

I am having an issue with ZF2 trying to use the table gateways and getting result sets:

I am trying to query two result sets (from two different tables/two different gateways) and send them to the view to be iterated through and placed on the screen.

(Simplified example):

```
function viewAction() {
    $table1 = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Model\Table\Table1');
    $table2 = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Model\Table\Table2');

    return new ViewModel([
        'table1' => $table1->fetchAll(),
        'table2' => $table2->fetchAll()
    ]);
}
```

With the Model\Table\Table1 and Model\Table\Table2 having a fetch all:

```
public function fetchAll() {
    return $this->tableGateway->select();
}
```

Then in my view:

```
...
<?php
foreach($table1 as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['col1']}</td><td>{$row['col2']}</td></tr>";
}
?>
...
<?php
foreach($table2 as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['col1']}</td><td>{$row['col2']}</td></tr>";
}
?>
...
```

**The problem is, $table1 will have no data when looping**.  However, if I instead do something like this (in the controller, instead of passing the result set to the view, passing $results1 and $results2 to the view):

```
$fetchAll = $table1->fetchAll();
$results1 = [];
foreach($fetchAll as $row) {
    $results1[] = $row;
}
$fetchAll = $table2->fetchAll();
$results2 = [];
foreach($fetchAll as $row) {
    $results2[] = $row;
}
```

Then all works fine.  I don't want to have to loop through the same set of data twice.  **So why does ZF2 prevent me from using two different ResultSets before all the data in a ResultSet has been accessed?**

Comment: You appear to have anaemic models. I wont repeat the quickstart guide in ZF2 - take a look at the quickstart guide & let us know any questions / issues http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Comment: I had solved my issue, forgot to come back and post an answer (and my question was a simplified view of what was really going on)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I was querying to different record sets one after the other, the database was still waiting for action to take place on the first query.  **I could only have one action record set at a time.**

There first solution was what I presented in the question, get a record set and loop through all the rows that are available before trying to query again.  This frees the record set as we have all the data.

The second solution (the one I have adapted), is to enable **Multiple Active Record Sets (MARS)** for the database connection.

I was able to do this by adding  `MARS_Connection=yes` to the dsn connection string for MSSQL.